# Org mode macro for including content of another org mode file

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to wrap my head around why the following macro does not work:

```
#+MACRO: INCLUDE_ORG #+INCLUDE: "$1::$2" :minlevel 3 :only-contents t
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
{{{INCLUDE_ORG(./somefile.org,Some long heading with spacesj)}}}
```

I was experimenting with putting quotes here and there without any progress. Using regular include without macro works just fine.

Could you please help me understand what causes the issue?

Comment: I have three questions: (1) Why do you think it is not working as expected? (2) What's the behavior you expect? and (3) what's the behavior you are getting?

Comment: Did you try escaping the spaces, e.g. `  ` with `\ `?

Comment: Following NickD's answer, I would rather use something like [yasnippet](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/) to expand manually your macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because macro expansion happens *after* include processing: by the time the macro is expanded and you have `#+INCLUDE:`  in the output, it is too late.

The [code](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/master/lisp/ox.el#L2948) is in the function `org-export-as` in file `ox.el`, ll.2948-2953:

```el
...
(org-export-with-buffer-copy
     ;; Run first hook with current back-end's name as argument.
     (run-hook-with-args 'org-export-before-processing-hook
                 (org-export-backend-name backend))
     (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
     (org-export--delete-comment-trees)
     (org-macro-initialize-templates)
     (org-macro-replace-all (append org-macro-templates
                    org-export-global-macros)
                parsed-keywords)
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed that behavior by applying following fix to `org-export-as` function in ox.el.

```
   (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
   (org-export--delete-comment-trees)
   (org-macro-initialize-templates)
   (org-macro-replace-all (append org-macro-templates
                                            org-export-global-macros)
                                  parsed-keywords)

   ;; Duplicate include, initialize, replace before refresh
   (org-export-expand-include-keyword)
   (org-export--delete-comment-trees)
   (org-macro-initialize-templates)
   (org-macro-replace-all (append org-macro-templates
                                            org-export-global-macros)
                                  parsed-keywords)
```

Comment: I did *not* suggest that (I just diagnosed the problem), but if it works for you, I'm OK with it. But note that this is a change that you will need to carry forward every time that the Org mode code is updated. That's not too bad with `git` but it can become a chore. Note also that if you ever want a macro that expands to a macro that expands to an include then you will have to repeat the code one more time - and so on :-). My suggestion would be to examine alternative implementations of what you are trying to do and see if you can limit yourself to what the current code allows.

Comment: Yep sorry for that. I've edited the post so that it does not include misinformation. I will think about alternative solutions.

Comment: I would be very interested to hear what solution you came up with